# Retrieve minute from datetime in shorter way

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
(@DurationFrom IS NULL OR datepart(minute, convert(varchar, DATEADD(SECOND,datediff(second, main.StartTime, main.EndTime) , 0),108)) >= @DurationFrom)
```

The query above works fine but seems like its too long. it there any other way that i can get the same result but shorter way

Comment: (1) Tag your query with the database you are using.  (2) Explain the logic  you want to implement, along with sample data and desired results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
WHERE 
  @DurationFrom is null or DATEADD(minute, @DurationFrom, main.StartTime) <= main.EndTime
```

This gives a more exact result than your current script, your current script compare using seconds, this also includes miliseconds

If you want to maintain the logic as in your current code, you can use this:

```
WHERE 
  @DurationFrom is null 
    or datediff(second, main.StartTime, main.EndTime)/60 >= @DurationFrom
```

This will also work for code where the difference between StartTime and  EndTime exceeds 60 minutes (which your current code doesn't check for)

Answer (score 2):

As per current query syntax you can do :

```
select . . .
from . . .
where (@DurationFrom is null or 
        datediff(minute, main.StartTime, main.EndTime)) >= @DurationFrom;
```

Comment: This will not give the correct result, datediff minute does not consider the seconds like the original script does. This means there will be 1 minute between '07:11:59' and '07:12:00'